# How can I calculated dates from another column and another table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

table 1:

```
|| *handtool_id* || *maintenance_interval_value* || *unit_unit_id* || *handtool_last_date_of_maintenance* || *handtool_next_date_of_maintenance* ||
||             1 ||                            1 ||              5 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
||             2 ||                            1 ||              6 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
||             3 ||                            4 ||              4 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
```

table 2:

```
|| *unit_id* || *unit_name* || *unit_value* || *unit_parent_id* ||
||         1 || Minute      ||            1 ||                1 ||
||         2 || Hour        ||           60 ||                1 ||
||         3 || Day         ||         1440 ||                1 ||
||         4 || Week        ||        10080 ||                1 ||
||         5 || Month       ||        32767 ||                1 ||
||         6 || Year        ||       525949 ||                1 ||
```

What is the right syntax for calculating the *handtool_next_date_of_maintenance* from  *maintenance_interval_value* and from *unit_unit_id*? Thank you

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily store that piece of information

Comment: What is my possibilites generate the next maintenace date from the interval what i need stored in the db?

Comment: What is the significance of `unit_parent_id`?

Comment: i storing in that table other units too for example weigt units with another parent id = 2

Comment: So it's not relevant to this problem?

Comment: yes, is not relevant. my bad ;/

Comment: Maybe it would help if you showed the desired result (and the calculation)

Comment: the next date = last date + (interval_value and unit_id)
int the first situation :
next date = 2014-11-07 + 1 month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say, it's wrong, and very confusing to change your question like this. You should rollback this question to the one Andrew Jones answered Nov 3, accept and upvote his answer, and then ask a new question.

That said, this would appear to get you something like what you're after (although how you arrived at figures of 32767 and 525949 is beyond me !?!)

```
SELECT *
     , h.handtool_last_date_of_maintenance 
     + INTERVAL h.maintenance_interval_value 
     * u.unit_value MINUTE x 
  FROM handtools h 
  JOIN units u 
    ON u.unit_id = h.unit_unit_id;
```

Comment: thank you man. Sorry for the inconvenience, i promise you i dont will changing the question in the future. but i dont have any other possibility. my bad :/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you insert to B, you want to insert into A. This is a good use of a MySQL trigger. I'm assuming an auto increment for web_content_id.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER new_language_id
AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A (web_content_const, i18n_language_codes_i18n_language_codes_id)
        VALUES ('SERVICES_HEADING', @i18n_language_codes_id),
        ('SERVICES_MAIN_TEXT', @i18n_language_codes_id),
        ('SERVICES_1_HEADING', @i18n_language_codes_id),
        ('SERVICES_1_TEXT', @i18n_language_codes_id);
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ok thanks, but what can i do when web_content_const values raising over the time? i must adding lines to the trigger for every web_content_const?

Comment: There's a couple ways you can do it, but adding to the trigger would probably be the simplest. The other method would be to create a table with the different values and have the trigger insert each row in the table. For a table with `val` as the column you're adding: `INSERT INTO A (web_content_const, i18n_language_codes_i18n_language_codes_id) SELECT val, @i18n_language_codes_id FROM C`

Comment: is there any way over by cross join?

Comment: I don't see how a cross join would solve this problem. The data has to be put into the database at some point. Like I said, I recommend doing this either through a second table or altering the trigger.